# CakePHP Form in an Element Causing Errors

Tags: forms, cakephp

I think this may be an easy solution, but I've spent an hour now investigating to no avail.

I have a registration form in an element that is being used in views belonging to different controllers. Using the "url" attribute, I've told it to submit to /users/register, but for some reason, the fields aren't submitting to the database.

Instead, there are errors for "undefined index" and a MySQL error for an undefined secondary key that I set (it's empty because it's not being submitted). Strangely, the form works fine if I include the element somewhere in the users views. Does anyone know why this is happening?

UPDATE - Here's the relevant code, sorry:

```
<?php 
    echo $form->create(array(
        'id' => 'signupform', 
        'url' => array(
            'controller' => 'users', 
            'action' => 'register'))); 
?>
```

The form fields are all correct, since the element works in the user controller's views anywhere. Do I need to include any other information in the creation of the form to point it more directly?

Comment: Please post the code for your element.

Comment: And what is the query produced by submitting this form? Do you use Security component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the model 'User' as the first parameter to the $form->create() method.

```
<?php 
    echo $form->create('User', array(
        'id' => 'signupform', 
        'url' => array(
            'controller' => 'users', 
            'action' => 'register')
        )
    ); 
?>
```

This will ensure that the form fields are named as data[User][field_name], and prevent you from seeing that undefined index error.

Hope this works for you!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code, it sounds like Cake is magically assuming that the Model is the one for the controller that controls the current view. When that controller is Users, it works correctly. When it is, say, Articles, it will be trying (and failing)  to fit the form fields to the Article model.

Without seeing any code, it is impossible to offer any more help.

EDIT:

If the form contains mixed models, e.g. User and Article, you *must* prefix the fieldnames like this:

```
$form->input('User.username');
$form->input('Article.title');
```

etc.

If you don't, the controller will assume they all belong to its own model.

Comment: I updated with the only part of the element code that could be causing the problem. Any ideas what the problem may be here? The action part of the form HTML appears to be going to the right place, but no data is being passed from the form outside of the user view...

Comment: Ah-ha! I didn't realize that CakePHP automatically put the model in there, but that makes perfect sense now that I think about it. I'll add a comment to the CakePHP docs for that section too in case someone has a similar problem. Thanks!!!

Comment: Ok, related problem: Is it possible to display error messages in an element? Right now, it redirects to the actual registration view and then displays the error messages. Do you know how to fix this?